# On failed form submission, prevent change to dropdown option (Javascript, Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working towards the tech degree at team treehouse and my 3rd project is to make a form interactive. I'll explain my issue in point form to make it easier.

- Credit card payment method needs to be selected on page load
- Change this method to Paypal but do not fill out all the required fields and hit submit
- Payment option reverts back to credit card but still shows paypal info

if anyone could point me in the right direction as to how to keep the paypal option selected on an unsuccessful form submit that would be awesome.

Here the link to my code: https://github.com/Allan-Glasier/InteractiveForm

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the Paypal info was shown, but you can use this info to initialize the selected option on page load event. For example:

```
    $(function(){
    //Get if the displayed info is for Paypal
    if($("div#<Paypal info div id>").is(":visible"){
    //Set Paypal option selected
    ....
    }
    })
```